# How to inject a Spring bean in to Camel DefultProducer

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have written a camel component by extending DefaultComponent and also have the associative classes implemetation for endpoint, consumer, producer. My producer is extending the camel DefaultProducer and I want to inject a spring bean inside this class, so that whenever a route will be executed like

```
<route id="myRoute"><from uri="file://inbox"/><to uri="myComp://outbox"/>
```

I will be able to get the file from the file system and store it into database. For storing the file into the DB I have a service class instantiated by the spring container, but whenever I inject that bean into MyProducer we are getting null.

Comment: Can you provide your whole XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recongnized the problem was not about Camel, it is related to the spring and I was injecting the bean in a wrong way. I resolved the problem by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface into my helper class and storing the spring context as static variable and with the help of this helper class I am able to get spring bean inside MyProducer class. Thanks for spring ApplicationContextAware interface.